# Drawing 3 dimension using python matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to draw the following chart using python.
Can you help me out?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'realtime':[2,3,4,2,4],
                   'esttime':[1,1,3,1,4],
                   'time of 5 mins': ['09:15','09:20','09:25','09:30','09:35']})
df
   realtime  esttime time of 5 mins
0         2        1           9:15
1         3        1           9:20
2         4        3           9:25
3         2        1           9:30
4         4        4           9:35
```

Convert your `time of 5 mins` to valid `datetime` object using [**`pd.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
df['time of 5 mins']=pd.to_datetime(df['time of 5 mins'],format='%H:%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Output:

Now, use `time of 5 mins` as X-Axis and Y-Axis for `realtime` and `esttime` and use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.plot.annotate`**](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) as 3-rd dimension.

```
index= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

plt.plot(df['time of 5 mins'],df['esttime'],marker='o',alpha=0.8,color='#CD5C5C',lw=0.8)
plt.plot(df['time of 5 mins'],df['realtime'],marker='o',alpha=0.8,color='green',lw=0.8)

ax= plt.gca() #gca is get current axes

for i,txt in enumerate(index):
    ax.annotate(txt,(df['time of 5 mins'][i],df['realtime'][i]))
    ax.annotate(txt,(df['time of 5 mins'][i],df['esttime'][i]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

To make the plot more complete add `legend`, `xlabel`, `ylabel`, `title`, and stretch the `X-Y Axis` ranges a little so that it will be visually aesthetic. More details about [`matplotlib.pyplot here`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [2, 3, 4, 2, 4]
y2 = [1, 1, 3, 1, 4]
a = ['9:15', '9:20', '9:25', '9:30', '9:35']
x = np.arange(5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='Real Time')
ax.plot(x, y2, label='Estimated Time')
plt.xticks(x, labels=a)
plt.xlabel('Time')
chartBox = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([chartBox.x0, chartBox.y0, chartBox.width*0.6, chartBox.height])
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 0.8), shadow=True, ncol=1)
plt.show()
```